# How to solve E/MediaRecorder: stop called in an invalid state: 4

Tags: android, audio, record

I am trying to record the audio and store it. Problem is When I am recording the Audio its getting started but while stopping it I am getting the error :

> E/MediaRecorder: stop called in an invalid state: 4

My code is :

```
     public void  RecordVoice(){
        recordVoice.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(checkPermissionFromDevice()){
                    pathSave  = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + " /" + UUID.randomUUID().toString() + "_audio_record.3gp";
                    setupMediaRecorder();
                    try {
                        mediaRecorder.prepare();
                        mediaRecorder.start();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    recordVoice.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    recordVoiceStop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Recording..",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    requestPermissionForAudio();
                }
            }
        });

        recordVoiceStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(mediaRecorder != null){
                    mediaRecorder.stop();
                    mediaRecorder.release();
                }
                recordVoice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                recordVoiceStop.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
        });
}
 private void setupMediaRecorder() {
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(pathSave);
}

private void requestPermissionForAudio() {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{ Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE }, REQUEST_RECORD_VOICE);
}

private boolean checkPermissionFromDevice() {
    int writeExternalStorageDevice = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    int recordAudioResult = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO);
    return  writeExternalStorageDevice == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && recordAudioResult == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
}
```

PS: I have given permission in manifect. Can anybody help me to solve this issue? Any suggestion is most welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check logs for the io exception around `prepare` / `start`.  State 4 by my estimation is the `DataSourceConfigured` state ( https://developer.android.com/images/mediarecorder_state_diagram.gif ) and the `stop` would fail in that state.  (Note that you print the stack trace but keep going with Toast indicating 'Recording'. ) Also may want to add a call to `setOnErrorListener`.

Comment: The recorder states are treated as a bit mask in the native implementation: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/android-4.2.2_r1.2/include/media/mediarecorder.h#96 .

Comment: There was a problem in saving the file in mobile storage. That's why this problem occurred. Though I solved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

**change that line**

```
            pathSave  = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + " /" + UUID.randomUUID().toString() + "_audio_record.3gp";
```

**To**

```
    pathSave  = getExternalCacheDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/audiorecordtest.3gp";
```

**and it will work**